# How to copy a file using Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, copying

Does anyone know of a way to copy files with Paperclip using S3 for storage? Before I try to write my own, I just wanted to make sure there wasn't already a way to do this. Thanks

Answer (score 28, accepted):

After some more messing around with paperclip, I figured it out. It's ridiculously simple to copy files!

```
# Stupid example method that just copies a user's profile pic to another user.
def copy_profile_picture(user_1, user_2)
  user_2.picture = user_1.picture
  user_2.save # Copied the picture and we're done!
end
```

This also works great with amazon s3. Sweet

Comment: The problem here, though, would be that if you have any kind of media editing or deleting, when user 1 edits or deletes their picture, user 2 will get those changes on their profile, right?