# Ruby: Paperclip, S3, and Deep-cloning

Tags: ruby, amazon-s3, paperclip

What I have is a Theme model, which contains many Assets.  Assets are using Paperclip and storing their file content in my Amazon AWS-S3 system.  I'm also using deep_clone because my customers have the ability to copy built in Themes and then modify them to their hearts content.  All the deep_clone stuff is working great, but when I deep_clone the assets, the old file contents don't get added to my S3 buckets.  The record gets saved to the database, but since the file-contents don't get saved with the new ID the file.url property points to a dead file.

I've tried calling paperclip's save and create method manually but I can't figure out how to get paperclip to "push" the file back to the bucket since it now has a new ID, etc....

```
require 'open-uri'

class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :theme
  attr_accessor :old_id
  has_attached_file :file,
                    :storage => "s3",
                    :s3_credentials => YAML.load_file("#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/aws.yml")[RAILS_ENV],
                    :bucket => "flavorpulse-" + RAILS_ENV,
                    :path => ":class/:id/:style.:extension"
  validates_attachment_presence :file
  validates_attachment_size :file, :less_than => 5.megabytes

  before_save :delete_assets_in_same_theme_with_same_name
  after_create :copy_from_cloned_asset

  private
  def delete_assets_in_same_theme_with_same_name
    Asset.destroy_all({:theme_id => self.theme_id, :file_file_name => self.file_file_name})
  end

  def copy_from_cloned_asset
    if (!old_id.blank?)
      if (old_id > 0)
        old_asset = Asset.find(old_id)
        if (!old_asset.blank?)
          self.file = do_download_remote_image(old_asset.file.url)
          self.file.save
        end
      end
    end
  end

  def do_download_remote_image (image_url)
    io = open(URI.parse(image_url))
    def io.original_filename; base_uri.path.split('/').last; end
    io.original_filename.blank? ? nil : io
  rescue # catch url errors with validations instead of exceptions (Errno::ENOENT, OpenURI::HTTPError, etc...)
  end
end
```

Any ideas on how I can get paperclip to push the file?  I also wouldn't be opposed to doing this using Amazon's aws-s3 gem but I couldn't seem to get that to work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this former question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739839/how-to-copy-a-file-using-paperclip), it should be possible with this simple line of code:

```
self.file = old_asset.file
```