# How do I copy the s3 assets of an association when deep-cloning a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

Along the lines of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3327669/ruby-paperclip-s3-and-deep-cloning), I'm using [deep_cloneable](https://github.com/moiristo/deep_cloneable) to copy a model with its single association. That association has an attached image (stored in s3), which I want copied at the time of the clone.

This is how I'm doing the deep-clone now - this clones the `gallery` along with its associated `photos`, and updates the copied `gallery` to have a new `location_id` based on some passed parameters:

```
new_gallery = @gallery.deep_clone(incude: :photos) do |original, copied_gallery|
  copied_gallery.location_id = gallery_params['Location_id']
end

new_gallery.save
```

My first thought was to somehow iterate over either the `original` or `copied_gallery` photos, to assign `photo.image = old_photo.image` within the overall `deep_clone` block, but I don't know if all of the necessary data is accessible/findable at that point.

From there, I wonder if there's access to the `(include: :photos)` portion of the `deep_clone` block. Similar to how I have access to both `original` and `copied_gallery`, if I could access the original & copied photos within the block, then I could easily assign values. I just don't know if that level of access exists.

If all else fails, I might be better off dropping the `(include: :photos)` portion of the `deep_clone` block. I could clone the gallery on its own, then clone the individual photos just after that - something like this:

```
new_gallery = @gallery.deep_clone do |original, copied_gallery|
  copied_gallery.location_id = gallery_params['Location_id']
end

new_gallery.save

@gallery.photos.each do |photo|
  new_photo = photo.deep_clone do |original, copied_photo|
    copied_photo.image = original.image
  end

  new_photo.save
end
```

That feels very heavy-handed, though.

Do you have any insight into the `(include: :photos)` portion of the `deep_clone` block, or do you have any other ideas on how to set the `image` for each of the `photos` being cloned?

Answer (score 1):

I misunderstood the block - all models are being processed in there, not just the one you called `deep_clone` on.

Take this example:

```
pirate.deep_clone :include => :parrot do |original, kopy|
  kopy.cloned_from_id = original.id if kopy.respond_to?(:cloned_from_id)
end
```

`kopy` refers to both data types, `pirate` and `parrot`. That's why you need to include the `if kopy.respond_to?(:cloned_from_id)` within the block - each model going through it (if you're using `include`) might not respond to the field you're attempting to work with.

So, in my case, I would do this:

```
new_gallery = @gallery.deep_clone(incude: :photos) do |original, copied_item|
  copied_item.location_id = gallery_params['Location_id']
  copied_item.image       = original.image if copied_item.respond_to?(:image)
end

new_gallery.save
```