# ruby copy a paperclip attachment from one model to another?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

I have two models like this:-

Model 1 - card - contains a representation of data of interest for front page
 attachment name = cardimage
Model 2 - user - contains the user
 attachment name = avatar

When I create! a new card, I want the avatar from the user model to be copied to the card   model as a new cardimage.

Is there a simple one liner for this?

Ruby/Rails/Paperclip

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739839/how-to-copy-a-file-using-paperclip

Comment: Do you need to store the attachment twice? If your User model is associated with the Card model you could avoid duplication.

Comment: That example is copying from one users profile to another. What is needed is to copy the image to a different model.

Comment: The card model is not associated. It is used independently to store random information and images from any model, real world data, tweets etc for a front page summary

Comment: So how will you know which user you ant the avatar from, current_user?

Comment: that will already be available in an instance variable..

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This should do the trick, you could use an `after_create` callback if the models are associated, if not I would recommend doing it in the controller action that creates the card.

```
instance_of_model_one.cardimage = instance_of_model_two.avatar
instance_of_model_one.save
```

Comment: This works correctly. I tried with the file name initially, but just the method is correct, paperclip handles the rest quite nicely, with correct id's etc. Thank you.

Comment: I think you need `instance_of_model_two.avatar.dup`

Comment: Nope, pretty sure you don't need to `dup` in this case.

Comment: Attachment styles are copied from the original url, then reprocessed. When duplicating manually reprocessed attachment, new_model.image.url(:thumbnail) is copied from original_model.image.url(:original) and reprocessed. Unless one saves the reprocess parameters (e.g. cropping) - no reprocessing is performed and all styles look the same as the original. I found an issue about it and offer a solution for manual copying:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17603045/copy-all-styles-of-a-paperclip-attachment-to-new-object-s3

Comment: https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/9#issuecomment-609304 works for S3

Answer (score 3):

```
old_avatar = model1.avatar;
model2.avatar.create(attachment: old_avatar.attachment);
model2.save;
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have 2 models:

- User
- Player

You have to copy `profile_image` from `User with id = 1` to `Player with id = 10`. You can perform the following:

```
user = User.find(1)
player = Player.find(10)

player.profile_image = user.profile_image
player.save!
```

Sometimes this might save the file but with a file size of 0 Bytes. In such cases try the following:

```
user = User.find(1)
player = Player.find(10)

player.profile_image = user.profile_image.url
player.save!
```

This shall do the work!

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, the approach mentioned by @cih should work:

```
instance_of_model_one.cardimage = instance_of_model_two.avatar
instance_of_model_one.save
```

But in my case, it was creating a blank file in S3. To resolve the issue, I tried the below approach and it worked:

```
instance_of_model_one.cardimage = instance_of_model_two.avatar.url
instance_of_model_one.save
```

Passing the URL instead of the object in the 1st statement resolved the issue.