# Rails Paperclip copy image with hash from one model to another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration, paperclip

I want migrate my images from one model to another.
My old model looks like:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

     has_attached_file :logo,
                  url: '/test/post/logo',
                  path: ':rails_root/uploads/test/post/:id/logo/:hash',
                  hash_secret: 'secret',
                  styles: { thumb: ['200x150>', :jpg], medium: ['320x240>', :jpg], large: ['480x360>', :jpg] }
end
```

the new model looks like the old one.

Currently i try to migrate the images with the following code snippet:

```
new_logo = post.logo
new_image.logo = new_logo
new_image.save
```

But unfortunately is doesn't work. I get the following error:

> No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen -
>   /abcde/fghjk/test/post/1/logo/43023e427c1deb69789bbf7b75cf32810fbb6354

When i search for the hash in the directory, it doesn't match some of the hashes.

Without hashing it will work like a charme but i need a solution with hashed attachments.

Have someone an idea to solve my problem?

Comment: Looked here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14224080/ruby-copy-a-paperclip-attachment-from-one-model-to-another

Comment: Yes tried it this way and thought it should work bis i got the error described above.

Comment: Maybe you have the old image saved with a path defined, which differs from that now?

Comment: The old image is in the expected path but the hash calculation during migration is incorrect and i don't know why.. the whole path is correct  except the hash

Comment: Can you show the code of your new model you mentioned.

Comment: It looks like the old one. the only difference is the name..

Answer (score 0):

You can read the file using .path and then assign the file object:

```
new_image.logo = File.open(post.logo.path)
new_image.save
```

Comment: I tried it, but strangely enough  the calculated hash in the path is not matching an existing one ..

Comment: Are you sure the file is where it's suposed to be? the url config is set to "url: '/test/post/logo'" without a hash, it looks like the path config shouldn't have the :hash or you have to add the :hash wildcard to the url config

Comment: also, the url does not have an :id wildcard!

Comment: The hash will be automatically added to the path. If i try to access a logo through an self build absolute path i got the following error:

'source sequence is illegal/malformed utf-8'

And yes i am sure the file is where i supposed it to be. I can add the :hash to the path config for sure but this will generate the same result as the described above one.