# Copying multiple attachments to another model in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails app with the model "quotes" and the model "orders".  Orders take data from Quotes upon creation. Both the "quotes" and "orders" have a has_many attachments relationship. How can I copy over all the attachments from the "quotes" to the "orders".  They do not have to recreate the file, just pointing to the same thing.

Comment: Is there anything that you've tried? Could you post some code?

Comment: @sjagr I tried to implement this method http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739839/how-to-copy-a-file-using-paperclip but it doesn't say anything about a has_many relationship.

Comment: And you didn't try `quotes.attachments = orders.attachments` or vice-versa?

Comment: I didn't think about that, I'll try right now and report back. (still new to rails)

Comment: Don't forget to use `save` after!

Comment: @sjagr Okay, that worked. I used
    order.attachments = quote.attachments in the controller where quote was set to a specific quote already.  Have all my helpful flags!

Comment: Glad to help. Remember that a lot of stuff in Ruby/RoR may be way simpler than you could ever think!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Akin to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739839/how-to-copy-a-file-using-paperclip), we found that you can just as easily do:

```
order.attachments = quote.attachments 
order.save
```

That's it!